# jquery regex strip information from email address

Tags: jquery, regex

First of: I am not looking to validate an email address.
I am looking for a solution to strip (remove) information from an email address.

**NAME@** domainname **.COM** **NAME@** need to be removed and **.COM** need to be **removed**.
NO validation.....

I am looking for a jQuery Regex solution to remove the following from an email address.

Example: info@domainname.com

info@ should be removed and .com should be removed.
But the name before the @ could be anything and the domain extension could also be anything. (ak .co.uk .br.com etc etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that everyone can see I did not want to validate an email address. Solved it myself.

```
 function myFunction() {
   var str = "this.name@domainname.com.uk";
  var afterComma = str.substr(str.indexOf("@") + 1).split(".")[0]; 
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = afterComma;
 }
```

Results in: domainname 
All before and including @ and all after . will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var str = "this@that.com";
    var str2 = str.replace(".", "").replace("@","");
    console.log(str2);
```

the output should look something like: thisthatcom
.replace js method should work fine here.